# window.location - javascript - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, postmessage

Odd issue. I am using jQuery `.postMessage()` to send messages from a secure `<iframe>` to the parent. Specifically I am sending a URL and have confirmed that the parent is receiving the URL - however, when I use try to set `window.location` to that URL, nothing happens.

The sent url:

```
http://mydomain.com/shop/507870?nav=ln-474#/shop/507870?gnrefine=1*COLOR_FAMILY*Brown%5E1*CLSR_TYP*Lace-Up%5E
```

The actual url:

```
http://mydomain.com/shop/507870?nav=ln-474#/shop/507870?gnrefine=1*COLOR_FAMILY*Brown%5E1*CLSR_TYP*Lace-Up%5E
```

They match. However, in Chrome, if I do a `console.log(loginConfig.redirectURL);` I get:

```
http://mydomain.com/shop/507870?nav=ln-474#/shop/507870?gnrefine=1*COLOR_FAMILY*Brown%5E1*CLSR_TYP*Lace-Up%5E

undefined
```

So, I think the `window.location` is getting the `undefined` value.

Any thoughts on why I would be getting two values when I use the `console.log`?

**Update**

logic:

```
if (message[1] != "") {
                $("#loginDialog").dialog("close");
                 loginConfig.redirectURL = message[1];
                window.location = loginConfig.redirectURL
                console.log('message: '+loginConfig.redirectURL);
}
```

config object:

```
var loginConfig = {
redirectURL: ""
}
```

**Further Update:**

the window.location works on any url without a hash. So for some reason, it will not load any urls with a hash.

Comment: So you get two lines in your console? Does it point to which lines in your JS file? They could be unrelated.

Comment: I don't see how we could possibly figure this out without seeing the relevant code.

Comment: window.location = loginConfig.redirectURL; the semicolon is typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part of your code is invalid:

```
var loginConfig = {
    redirectURL = ""
}
```

It needs to be this:

```
var loginConfig = {
    redirectURL: ""
}
```

If this leads to an error which keeps loginConfig from being properly declared with the desired property that could partly explain some unexpected behavior.  You should certainly look in your browser error log and see if it reports any errors.

Comment: Updated - I had a typo in the question

Comment: @Jason - I'd suggest you should do a `console.log()` of `message[1]` right at the beginning of your `if` block and see EXACTLY what it is coming through the messaging system as.  Pay careful attention to whether there are line breaks in it or any special characters that might not be allowed in URLs.  Then you can find out whether you need to look before this `if` statement or after it for the problem.

Comment: no line breaks - url's match 100%, and are valid (meaning they resolve).

Comment: @Jason - Is it possible that `message[1]` gets changed by `$("#loginDialog").dialog("close");`?

Comment: No - I even tried it by commenting out that bit. So I'm at a bit of a loss here - I'm not sure a `preventDEfault` anywhere would be causing a collision with window.location, and I haven't got any other ideas at the moment.

Comment: @Jason - Can we see a page with this actual code in it with instructions for how to trigger it so we can step through in the debugger?

Comment: unfortunately, I can't really post code - as it's on a dev server and it's too complex to create a fiddle. I do have a fix, where I needed to `return false` after window.location, but I'm not sure I understand the technical underpinnings of why...

Comment: @Jason - Here's a theory: If the click that initiates this was on a link that has an href, then perhaps that link was overriding your window.location set unless you returned false to cancel the following of the link.  If there was a `#` in the window.location set, then the page would keep operating after the window.location and the link in the href would end up overriding your window.location set.  If the link in the window.location set did not have a `#`, then a new page would start right away stopping the rest of the execution and it would work.

Comment: decent theory - I already gave you credit, but it would make a good answer.